# How to make foreach loop take only value in php?

Tags: php, button, foreach

I am working on a **php code** from Code#A as shown below in which on debug (Line#A) prints the following:

**Code#A**

```
$mp4_files = array_values($mp4_files);

print_r($mp4_files);   // Line#A
```

> Output from Line#A:

```
Array ( [0] => 36031P.mp4 [1] => hello.mp4 )
```

---

**Code#B**

```
print_r($_POST['id']);   // Line#B

  if (!empty($_POST['id']))
  {
     foreach ($mp4_files as $f)
         {   
             print_r($f); // Line#C prints 2 values 36031P.mp4hello.mp4
             $parts = pathinfo($f);
             switch ($parts['extension'])
             {
                 case 'mp4' :
                 $filePath = $src_dir . DS . $f;
                 system('ffmpeg -i ' . $filePath . ' -map 0:2 -ac 1 ' . $destination_dir . DS . $parts['filename'] . '.mp3', $result);
             }
         }
   }
```

**Line#B** from Code#B has **2 values**: **0** and **1** which comes on the click of a button from 2 different rows.

When **1st row button** is clicked, **value 0** show up at  **Line#B**

When **2nd row button** is clicked, **value 1** show up at **Line#B**

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I should make in the **php code (Code#B)** above **(which have Line#B and Line#C)** so that:

When 1st row button is clicked, **Line#C prints 36031P.mp4**.

When 2nd row button is clicked, **Line#C prints hello.mp4**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, using`foreach` will loop through the whole array, as no stop point was indicated.

**Try the following...**

```
    for($i=0; $i <= count($mp4_files); $i++) {
        if($i == $_POST['id']) {
            $parts = pathinfo( $mp4_files[$i] );
            switch ($parts['extension']) {
                //
            }
        break;
        }
    }
```

You can build on it from there. I'm sorry I'm typing from a mobile device, so it's not easy. I'll send something better as soon as I lay my hands on my machine.

**EDITED**

*Try the following in your code*

```
    print_r($_POST['id']);   // Line#B
    if (!empty($_POST['id'])) {
        foreach ($mp4_files as $key => $f) {
            if($key == $_POST['id']) {
                print_r($f); // Line#C prints 2 values 36031P.mp4hello.mp4
                $parts = pathinfo($f);
                switch ($parts['extension']) {
                    case 'mp4' :
                    $filePath = $src_dir . DS . $f;
                    system('ffmpeg -i ' . $filePath . ' -map 0:2 -ac 1 ' . $destination_dir . DS . $parts['filename'] . '.mp3', $result);
                    break;
                }
            }
            break; //stop further iteration after the condition is met
        }
    }
```

Note the additional `$key` inside the`foreach` declaration and how I later used it for comparison.

Comment: **This is a comment on the original question. I don't have enough reputation atm to add it as a comment** => `print_r($f); // Line#C prints 2 values 36031P.mp4hello.mp4` This output is a concatenated result of two different `print_r`'s as you're performing a complete iteration over the whole`Array`. To show this clearly, try => `print_r($f); echo "\n";`

Comment: I am modifying my question. In the foreach loop conversion of mp4 into mp3 is happening.

Comment: Just modified my question. Let me know how it looks.

Comment: As @parsonsbot has explained and as I understood your question, you only want to print a single value from your array which corresponds with the `$_POST['id']`? Note that calling a `foreach` on an array without a match condition or `break`, `continue` etc statement, the whole array will be iterated, which means, all entries will be printed. To avoid this, check to only use the value when the `Array index == $_POST['id']`, and `break` out of the loop when your condition is met. **I will edit my answer to show the complete code**

Comment: Right and yes, I have removed break from my code. In my code, for some reasons its not going switch statement. Not sure what is the issue. I have put echo "Hello World" inside switch statement and its not printing anything.

Comment: I tried with this code and it seems to be working fine:

      `if (!empty($_POST['id']))
     {
         for($i=0; $i <count($mp4_files); $i++) {
        if($i == $_POST['id']) {
       $f = $mp4_files[$i];
             $parts = pathinfo($f);
    print_r($parts);
             switch ($parts['extension'])
             {
                 case 'mp4' :
                     $filePath = $src_dir . DS . $f;
                     system('ffmpeg -i ' . $filePath . ' -map 0:2 -ac 1 ' . $destination_dir . DS . $parts['filename'] . '.mp3', $result);
             }
         }
   }
   }`

Comment: The only issue is that its not going switch statement. Let me know what is the issue.

Comment: I have accepted your answer but I came back with another [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56519616/how-to-use-pathinfo-in-php). I am wondering you can have a look.

Answer (score 1):

If the `$_POST['id']` is always consistent with the indexes returned by `array_values`, this will work:

```
$mp4Files = array_values($mp4Files);

if (
    !empty($_POST['id']) &&
    !empty($mp4Files[$_POST['id']])
) {
    print_r($mp4Files[$_POST['id']]); // Line#C
}
```