# How to use pathinfo in php?

Tags: php, ffmpeg, switch-statement, http-status-code-500, pathinfo

I am working on a php code as shown below on which Line#A prints the following array (shown below php code). My code doesn't seems to go inside switch statement. I am not sure why.

I added `print_r($parts)` at Line A in order to print the value of $parts.

> php code:

```
<?php
    if (!empty($_POST['id']))
    {
    for($i=0; $i <count($mp4_files); $i++) {
    if($i == $_POST['id']) {
    $f = $mp4_files[$i];
    $parts = pathinfo($f);
    print_r($parts);                    // Line A
    switch ($parts['extension'])
    {
    echo "Hello World";                 // Line B
    case 'mp4' :
    $filePath = $src_dir . DS . $f;
    system('ffmpeg -i ' . $filePath . ' -map 0:2 -ac 1 ' . $destination_dir . DS . $parts['filename'] . '.mp3', $result);
    }
    }
    }
    }
?>
```

> Output (Line#A):

```
Array 
(
    [dirname]  => .
    [basename] => hello.mp4
    [extension] => mp4
    [filename] => hello
)
```

I have used `echo "Hello World"` at Line B but for some reasons, its not getting printed and throwing `500 internal server error` on console.

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I should make in the php code so that it goes inside switch statement.

Comment: For debugging purpose: **1** Move `echo "Hello World";` into the first case, then add a `default` case in which you'll just print out the argument value. This would give you an idea of what you're switching. **2** Try returning just the extension, since that's what you're interested in for now => `$parts = pathinfo( $f, PATHINFO_EXTENSION )`. This will return a string. Print the string, then move on.

Answer (score -1):

The error 500 is caused by `echo "Hello World"` at Line B which is outside of case `mp4`.

Your switch statement should be like this.

```
switch ($parts['extension']) {
    case 'mp4':
        echo "hello world";
        $filePath = $src_dir . DS . $f;
        system('ffmpeg -i ' . $filePath . ' -map 0:2 -ac 1 ' . $destination_dir . DS . $parts['filename'] . '.mp3', $result);
        break;
}
```

Comment: I have tried inside as well. It’s returning the same error

Comment: Try to enable php error reporting, paste this at the very start of your script.

`ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Then run the script again and paste the error message here.